# How can I use variables that are declared in another class?

Tags: java, parsing, variables, apache-poi

I am automating an email to be sent nightly. The "Send email" class contains the variables  `mailFrom` and `mailTo`. `ExcelReader` is a prerequisite class that reads the cells of an Excel worksheet that will contain the email addresses . I need my "Send email" (`SendCf`) class to get it's `mailFrom` and `mailTo` variables from the `ExcelReader` class (which gets it's variables from the Excel sheet's cells).

The purpose is so other people can modify an Excel sheet with different To/From email addresses, and my email sent nightly will reflect that. So I need to pull from the Excel sheet every time I send an email (not sure how to make that method run as a prerequisite to the email either).

First, my `ExcelReader`. It declares the values of variables `a1Val` and `b1Val` (the cells that contain the needed email adresses).

```
package com.test.Email;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException; 
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new  FileInputStream("C:/Users/TEST.xlsx");
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
            XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            XSSFRow row1 = worksheet.getRow(0);
            XSSFCell cellA1 = row1.getCell((int) 0);
            String a1Val = cellA1.getStringCellValue();
            XSSFCell cellB1 = row1.getCell((int) 1);
            String b1Val = cellB1.getStringCellValue();
```

So now we have variables set from excel. The mailTo and mailFrom are in cells A1 and B1. Now, i need my Send Email class to grab A1 and B1 from the ExcelReader class and assign their values to the sender and recipient. I know what I have below is very incorrect.

```
package com.test.Email;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

     public class SendCF {

        //Not sure about this, I think I need to declare a local ExcelReader here?
        ExcelReader cfExcel = new ExcelReader();


     public static void main(String[] args) 

            String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            String port = "587";
//These two variables, I need to get from the excel sheet via the ExcelReader class.
            String mailFrom = cfExcel.a1Val; 
            String mailTo = "cfExcel.b1Val;
            String password = "QAtesting";

            // after this I compose the email and send it.
```

edit: I now declare variables outside of the main method, but it won't allow me to make them public. I get "Illegal modifier for the variable a2Val; only final is permitted"

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;


import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelReader {
                {
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new     FileInputStream("C:/Users/test.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
        XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        XSSFRow row1 = worksheet.getRow(0);
        XSSFCell cellA1 = row1.getCell((int) 0);
        String a1Val = cellA1.getStringCellValue();
        XSSFCell cellB1 = row1.getCell((int) 1);
        String b1Val = cellB1.getStringCellValue();
        XSSFCell cellC1 = row1.getCell((int) 2);
        String c1Val = cellC1.getStringCellValue();
        XSSFCell cellD1 = row1.getCell((int) 3);
        String d1Val = cellD1.getStringCellValue();
        XSSFCell cellE1 = row1.getCell((int) 4);
        String e1Val = cellE1.getStringCellValue();
        XSSFCell cellF1 = row1.getCell((int) 5);
        String f1Val = cellF1.getStringCellValue();

      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    //dont think I need anything here?

    }
}
```

Comment: The variables need to be global. You can call it with ClassName.varableName

Comment: create getters and setters for the variables you need to share between classes in the class that has them currently (ExcelReader). Use the get method for the variables in the class you need to use them in (SendCF)

Comment: @dsidler check out my answer...

Answer (score 3):

You have `a1Val` and `b1Val` defined in your main method these variables will only be accessible in that scope. If you want to access them outside the `class` you need to make them global variables. If you want to directly access them they need to have the `public` modifier or you can use `private` and create `getters` and `setters` second option is recommended.

Method 1:

```
public class ExcelReader {
    public String a1Val;
    public String b1Val;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Access like this:

```
    cfExcel.a1Val;
```

Method 2:

```
public class ExcelReader {
    private String a1Val;
    private String b1Val;

    public String geta1Val()
    {
        return this.a1Val;
    }

    public String getb1Val()
    {
        return this.b1Val;
    }

    public void seta1Val(String a1Val)
    {
        this.a1Val = a1Val;
    }

    public void setb1Val(String b1Val)
    {
        this.b1Val = b1Val;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Access like this:

```
cfExcel.geta1Val();
cfExcel.seta1Val("test");
```

********************************************************UPDATE**********************************************************

This is how it should look:

```
public class ExcelReader {
    public String a1Val;
    public String b1Val;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new  FileInputStream("C:/Users/TEST.xlsx");
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
            XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            XSSFRow row1 = worksheet.getRow(0);
            XSSFCell cellA1 = row1.getCell((int) 0);
            a1Val = cellA1.getStringCellValue();
            XSSFCell cellB1 = row1.getCell((int) 1);
            b1Val = cellB1.getStringCellValue();
```

Comment: This is a good explanation of the use of `getters` and `setters` for someone who has a complete understanding of `Java Objects` and `Scope`

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I think I'll go with Method 1, since it's doubtful any other dev is going to be accessing this class, and I simply need to read a value from excel and use it as a variable. I'll never need to change the value in the code. But I'm running into an issue with your solution. I can't declare variables in `ExcelReader` as `public`, it gives me the error "Illegal modifier for the variable a1Val; only final is permitted"

Comment: @dsidler how are you declaring them can you post the code in your question? Should be an easy fix I just need to see how you are trying to declare them...

Comment: @dsidler no you need to declare them in the `Class` scope. That is probably the problem. Once declared in the `Class` scope (exactly like I have in my answer) then you can access them in your `main` method and any other methods in the class without re-declaring them. They are `global variables`.

Comment: @dsidler declare them right like this `public class ExcelReader {
    public String a1Val;
    public String b1Val;` then don't declare them again in your `main` method just use them.

Comment: I added my updated code, the main method is just empty now, I need these variables for another class. So, isn't that what I'm doing? Declaring them in the class scope with `String a1Val = cellA1.getStringCellValue();`?

Comment: @dsidler there I just posted an update. You can't put any code other than declarations outside of a method.  You might want to read up on `Java` scope and global variables...